# O que é um tipo Resource em PHP? Para que serve?

Tags: php

Sou novato na linguagem PHP, estudando sobre o mesmo, me deparei com um tipo especial disponível pela linguagem, o tipo `resource`. Encontrei uma definição para a ela:

> **Resource**
>
> Um recurso é uma variável especial, que mantém uma referência a um
>   recurso externo. Recursos são criados e usados por funções especiais.

Fonte: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.resource.php

O que é um tipo resource? Para que serve? Qual a sua aplicabilidade na prática?

Answer (score 7):

[resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) é dos tipos do php, ele é usando para vários propositos como fazer conexões com banco de dados, abrir/manipular arquivos ou ainda trabalhar com streams.

Como o manual fala basicamente o resorce é algo devolvido através de um função especifica(pode ser o `fopen`, `mysqli_connect` etc) que se comunicada com algo externo em outras palavras ele é um handler(manipulador).

[Lista de resources no PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php)

Comment: rray, um resource pode ser um arquivo numa função fopen() por exemplo?

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva, um resource não pode ser manipulado diretamente, somente através de funções. Já percebeu qtos resources são passados para o MySQLi no modo procedural?

Comment: Não, você poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 3):

Bem, para mim a palavra **resource** (recurso) tem um significado bem claro e é um pouco difícil explicar o significado de uma palavra que é autoexplicativa.
Talvez com analogia fique mais claro o que são recursos: Se você pensar que uma determinada coisa pode prover **meios** ou **diretivas** para se obter/chegar a outra determinada coisa, então apenas pense que esses meios são nada mais que recursos.

Então em PHP faz realmente sentido que um link de conexão seja um recurso, um stream/canal de uma conexão FTP, um manipulador de arquivo criado pelo `fopen()` ou um socket de conexão. Todos eles são "pontos" a partir dos quais se operam outras ações para se chegar a alguma coisa/resultado.

**Resource types** foram criados no `PHP 3` para compensar a falta de objetos, então, naturalmente, você poderia (na verdade você pode) pensar que são análogos a objetos onde funções retornando `resources` seriam construtores de objetos e funções manipulando através do recurso seriam como métodos destes objetos.

Ainda, eu não entendo o porquê do manual se referir como "tipo de variável" quando na verdade é apenas um tipo primitivo especial, mas talvez seja apenas para explicitar que a variável "lembra" uma referência.

Answer (score 0):

**Resource** - 
Segundo a documentação oficial do PHP, é "Um recurso é uma variável especial, que mantém uma referência a um recurso externo. Recursos são criados e usados por funções especiais."

**Fonte** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.resource.php

**Tipos de resource existentes**
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/resource.php

**Alguns exemplos**

***Curl*** - faz requisições para envio e download de dados (Utilizado geralmente para comunicar com Webservices (SOAP/REST), para fazer download/upload via servidor;

**XML** para trabalhar com XML no PHP de forma nativa;

**Imap** para e-mail (envio/recebimento), manipulação de caixas de correio eletronico.

**ODBC/mysql/dbase/dba** para manipulação de bancos de dados, entre outros.

Comment: Existem vários métodos associados a cada item, apenas ilustrei o nome como são encontrados.

Comment: Seriam Plugins/Bibliotecas os nomes mais apropriados, as chamadas extensões do PHP, geralmente configuradas no **php.ini**. Geralmente elas já vem com o PHP, porém novas e mais recentes podem ser instaladas.