# quero pega um saldo atual e somar com saldo anterior

Tags: php, mysql

Esse sistema e pra fazer operações bancarias o usuário vai ter que fazer o deposito só ele digita um valor que ele quera depositar  e no banco ele vai ter que somar com o saldo atual só que não esta funcionando.
ele esta colocando um numero 7 e não esta faazendo a soma

```html
<?php
$idConta=$_POST['idConta'];
$valor=$_POST['valor'];

$consu= mysql_query("select saldo from conta where  idConta=$idConta");

$saldoatual = $consu + $valor;


$up = mysql_query("UPDATE conta SET saldo='$saldoatual'  WHERE idConta=$idConta");



?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não precisa nem do `SELECT`, pode fazer direto no `UPDATE` desta forma `UPDATE conta SET saldo = saldo + '$saldoatual'  WHERE idConta=$idConta`

Comment: `mysql_query` retorna uma referência a um conjunto de resultados, em vez do próprio conjunto de resultados, então você  para `$consu` terá algo parecido com `Resource id #3`. Você precisa chamar uma função como mysql_fetch_array ou mysql_fetch_assoc para ler o próprio resultado do objeto do conjunto de resultados (e o que você obterá será um array). Esse valor: Resource id #3 é o retorno de uma query, indicando tb a posição da memória em que foi alocada

Comment: Saiba mais sobre Resource em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90764/o-que-%C3%A9-um-tipo-resource-em-php-para-que-serve/90771#90771

Answer (score 1):

Seu código esta errado `mysql_query` não retorna dados, ele retorna o manipulador da query executada, então deve-se usar `mysql_fetch_assoc` para pegar os valores, por exemplo:

> ps: adicione `isset` para checar se as variáveis vieram via POST corretamente

```
if (isset($_POST['idConta']{0}, $_POST['valor']{1})) {

    $idConta=$_POST['idConta'];
    $valor=$_POST['valor'];
    $up = false;

    $consu = mysql_query("select saldo from conta where  idConta=$idConta");

    if ($consu) {
        $dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($consu);

        $saldoatual = $dados['saldo'] + $valor;

        $up = mysql_query("UPDATE conta SET saldo='$saldoatual'  WHERE idConta=$idConta");
    } else {
         echo 'Erro:', mysql_error();
    }
}
```

---

### Extra

No entanto recomendo se atualizar e deixar de usar essa API (funções que começam com o prefixo `mysql_`) que já é tão obsoleta, para acessar o seu banco mysql prefira as novas APIs como:

- PDO
- mySqli